# A quick question about Monte Carlo integration

Tags: numerical-integration

I'm trying to improve the accuracy of a numerical integral of a very complicated function using the Monte Carlo Method by changing the MaxPoints. While doing that I asked to myself if it is better to perform a lot of (say 10) Monte Carlo integrations and then perform the average of all of them or to just increase the value of MaxPoints by a factor 10.

As an example I have performed 7 Monte Carlo integrations using "MaxPoints = $10^6$"

```
fourkintegral[fun_, k1_, k2_, k3_, k4_, x3_, x5_, x7_, points_] := 
 With[{sol = 
    NIntegrate[(2 Pi) k1 k2 k3 k4 fun Cos[2 (x3 - x5 - x7)], {k1, 0, 
      Infinity}, {k2, 0, Infinity}, {k3, 0, Infinity}, {k4, 0, 
      Infinity}, {x3, 0, 2 Pi}, {x5, 0, 2 Pi}, {x7, 0, 2 Pi}, 
     Method -> {"MonteCarlo", "MaxPoints" -> points}, 
     IntegrationMonitor -> ((errors = Through[#@"Error"]) &) ]}, 
  Around[sol, Total@errors]]
```

and then I did

```
fourkintegral[funint[1], k[1], k[3], k[5], k[7], x3, x5, x7, 10^6]
```

7 times ("funint[1]" is my complicated function) and I performed the average.

The result was

```
Out[64]= Around[0.0007229541751627402, 0.0004192286316295475]
```

On the other hand doing the same integral by changing the value of MaxPoints by a factor 7 I obtained the following result

```
In[66]:= fourkintegral[funint[1], k[1], k[3], k[5], k[7], x3, x5, x7,7*10^6]

Out[66]= Around[0.0003400475222668622, 0.000559829413446022]
```

The error estimates for the first result is better and therefore I have the following question:

**Is it better to perform the average o $N$ Monte Carlo Integrals using $P$ points or just making one integral using $N \times P$ points?**

Comment: While this seems more a question for a mathematics/statistics site than a Mathematica one, the question leads me to wonder about how Mathematica implements `MonteCarlo" and whether it should deliver different results.  I hope someone from Wolfram chimes in on this.